# Agora Flexible classroom - how to handle exit classroom event?

Tags: agora.io

Using flexible class room by following the steps provided at https://docs.agora.io/en/agora-class/agora_class_quickstart_web?platform=Web, I need to handle the event when a user exits a class. Unable to identify the exit class event. It would be nice if anyone can help me out on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [Classroom SDK API Reference](https://docs.agora.io/en/agora-class/agora_class_api_ref_web?platform=Web) then it should work if you have followed all the steps from the documentation.

If you are following the [Server Side RESTful API Reference](https://docs.agora.io/en/agora-class/agora_class_restful_api?platform=Web) then you can use the [following API](https://docs.agora.io/en/agora-class/agora_class_restful_api?platform=Web#description-1).

- Endpoint: `/{region}/edu/apps/{appId}/v2/rooms/{roomUUid}/users/{userUuid}/exit`
- Method: POST

Let me know in the comment if this is not what you were implementing or any error logs you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

On `AgoraEduSDK.launch`, there is a listener option that shows both events on room entering and exit

```
...
listener: (evt) => {
    console.log('evtName', evt)
},
...
```